# Start Icon in Materal Design 3's Input Text seems to be ignoring MinSize property

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I've been trying to utilize leading icons in my input texts while developing a mobile app, however, I cant seem to resize the icon to match the size of the input text.

> code 1:

[image]

> result 1:

[image]

Also tried without using the scaleType property, however, it just worsens it's sizing:

> code 2:

[image]

> result 2:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.